# I hope this is the correct forum for temperature related question

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I have about (this is experimental) 0.75 to 1 liter of water. Ive found I can use 400W of power through peltiers to reduce water flowing through at 1L/minute from 32C to 20C in about 1 to 1.5 minutes through a 0.25 lpm flow rate tube that cools by absorbing 8C per minute (thus maintaining a roughly 20C temperature). There is also other power consumed by fans and voltage converters but for this I'm simply addressing the water temperature. I assumed at first this would be Wh (watt hours required) to achieve this but my pack DOD (depth of discharge) isn't holding up. I have calculated everything. Resistance, amps being pulled, voltage to meet temperature settings, temperature probed before and after cooling. Does anyone have a clue what I should expect from a 3s15p battery pack with 480Wh  and only feeding the peltiers 7.5v from a 11.1A source (forget the loss from regulators and fans...they are accounted for through a separate calculation and power source)

Comment: Is this a question about a system for cooling water or just a simple question about battery pack capacity?

Comment: Well...I guess it applies to both. More curious about the battery capacity since I've figured out the cooling requirements but then again there could be a mistake in my calculations and implementation of the cooling that is creating the discrepancy.

Comment: Diameter of tube, Reynolds number ie laminar or turbulent, fully developed flow? This is a heat transfer problem - covered in many texts such as Heat transfer by Simenon. For the power, start with power in = power out and the capacity of the battery pack - real not imagined.

Comment: Diameter of tube is 6mm and tube walls are 1mm so 4mm flow of about 1 liter per minute. About 1000 for Reynolds No. and probably laminar flow.